# Retain value from nested for loop

Tags: r

So basically I am trying the following loop:

```
rawData = read.csv(file = "SampleData.csv")

companySplit = split(rawData, rawData$Company)

NameOfCompany <- numeric()
DateOfOrder <- character()
WhichProducts <- numeric()


for (i in 1:length(companySplit)){
  

  company_DateSplit = split(companySplit[[i]], companySplit[[i]]$Date)
  
  for (j in 1:length(company_DateSplit)){
    
    WhichProducts[j] <- (paste0(company_DateSplit[[j]]$ID, collapse=","))
    DateOfOrder[j]   <- (paste0(company_DateSplit[[j]]$Date[1]))
    
    NameOfCompany[j] <- (paste0(companySplit[[i]]$Company[[1]]))
  }
  
}


df <- data.frame(NameOfCompany,DateOfOrder, WhichProducts)
write.csv(df, file = "basket.csv")
```

If you check basket.csv there is output for only company D. It is not writing because of nesting of *for* loops I guess. I am not able to get out of it.

I need exact output as basket.csv but for all companies.

> Here are the CSVs:
>
> [Input Data: Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skad00sh/cs-go/master/SampleData.csv)
>
> [Output of code basket.csv: Link](https://github.com/skad00sh/cs-go/blob/master/basket.csv)

The output should look like this:

```
Company,Date, All IDs comma seperated.
e.g.
A,Jan-18,(1,2,4)
A,Feb-18,(1,4)
B,Jan-18,(2,3,4)
```

I'm able to get it from the above code. But Not able to save it in CSV for all A,B,C,D companies. It saves values for only company D which is the last value in looping. (check output file link)

Comment: `companySplit` is a list, so you can easily use `lappy` to iterate your function over its elements instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: It would help to know what your output should look like. The output you've given us doesn't really make a lot of sense as you've really only introduced some NAs because of the default "stringsAsFactors = TRUE", which means you have a bunch of NAs where the factors are missing. Also, what is `paste0(company_DateSplit[[j]]$Date[1])` supposed to do? `paste0("blah")` will return `"blah"`. And what are you collapsing?

Comment: @gersht I updated the question. Sorry for lesser explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error is that you import your data without the parameter `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` which happens all the time. Also, looping in R is usually less efficient and harder to reason about than using a more functional approach. I think what you're trying to do can be done with the aggregate function

```
rawData <- read.csv(file = "SampleData.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- aggregate(ID ~ Company + Date, data = rawData, FUN = paste, collapse = ",")
colnames(df) <- c("NameOfCompany", "DateOfOrder", "ID")
df = split(df, df$NameOfCompany)
```

Or using a tidy approach

```
df <- rawData %>% group_by(Company, Date) %>% 
    summarise(WhichProducts=paste(ID,collapse=',')) %>%
    rename(DateOfOrder = Date) %>%
    rename(NameOfCompany = Company) %>%
    group_split()
```

Comment: I've updated the question for output. Sorry for lesser explanation.