# Unique Count and total count in dataframe with some operations

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have the following data:

[image]

And I want its output as following:

[image]

Thanks to my last question I was able to get half of the output.

Which is:

[image]

But how to get the output of remaining columns? I tried some for loops with spilt but no luck.

> Links:
>
> [SampleData.csv](https://github.com/skad00sh/cs-go/blob/master/SampleData.csv)
>
> [LINK to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428771/retain-value-from-nested-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Company, Date) %>%
  summarise(Items = toString(ID),
            No.of.Items.Bought = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  mutate(No.of.Items.Did.Not.Buy = max(No.of.Items.Bought) - No.of.Items.Bought)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Also, can you help me add one more column with the total number of items? e.g. For **A** total number of items are 3 i.e. 16,17,21 considering both months together. Let's assume Nov-19 **A** bought _ID_ 18,19. So now total count is 5. So I want total count as 5 in front of all rows of A. same for B. Company.  [HERE IS THE NEW TABLE IMAGE.](https://imgur.com/POipSxz)   here is the image

Comment: @skad00sh Never add images of data. It is not possible to copy/paste it. As far as your question is concerned you can add `n()` in the last `mutate` like `mutate(No.of.Items.Did.Not.Buy = max(No.of.Items.Bought) - No.of.Items.Bought, 
       Total.Items = n())`